# I made a todo app with the help of provider package, but whenever restart my app it can't save the last added items. please take a look at my code

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import 'package:todo/taskScreen.dart';
    
    import 'package:todo/task_data.dart';
    
    
    void main() {
    
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_)=>Taskdata(),
          child: MaterialApp(
            restorationScopeId: 'root',
            home:taskScreen(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

// homepage

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:todo/task_data.dart';
    import 'list_tile.dart';
    import 'addTaskScreen.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    
    class taskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){
            showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context){return
           AddtaskScreeen();
            });
          },child:
          Icon(Icons.add),),
          body: SafeArea(child:
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
    
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60,left: 20,right: 20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [CircleAvatar(
                    child: Icon(Icons.list,size: 30,),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    radius: 30,
                  ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    Text('TODO',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,fontSize: 50),
                    ),
                    Text('${Provider.of<Taskdata>(context).tasks.length } Task',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 18),),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,)
    
    
                  ],
    
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30),topRight: Radius.circular(30)),
                ),
                  child: ListViewing(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    
    
        );
      }
    
    
    }
    
    class ListViewing extends StatelessWidget {
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Consumer<Taskdata>(
          builder: (context,taskData,child){
            return ListView.builder(itemCount: taskData.tasks.length,
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                  return ListTiling(isChecked: taskData.tasks[index].isDone,
                    taskText: taskData.tasks[index].name,
                    chCallback:
                        (bool ?newValue) {
                    taskData.udatetask(taskData.tasks[index]);
    
                    },
                    longPress: (){
                    taskData.deleteTask(taskData.tasks[index]);
                    },
                  );
                  //
    
                }
    
    
            );
          },
    
        );
      }
    }
```

// next page

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import 'package:todo/task_model.dart';
    import 'task_data.dart';
    class AddtaskScreeen extends StatelessWidget {
    
    
      TextEditingController newtext=TextEditingController();
      String?name1;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          color:Color(0xff757575) ,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                topRight: Radius.circular(30),
              )
    
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20 ,horizontal: 40),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    
                children: [
                  Text('Add Task',textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,fontSize: 30),),
                  TextField(
                    onChanged: (value){
                      name1=value;
                    },
                    controller: newtext,
                    autofocus: true,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
    
                  ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
    
    
                    Provider.of<Taskdata>(context,listen: false).addTask(name1!);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
    
    
                  }, child: Text('Add',style: TextStyle(fontSize:30 ,color: Colors.black87),),)
    
    
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

// task data

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:todo/task_model.dart';
    import 'task_data.dart';
    
    class Taskdata extends ChangeNotifier{
      List<task> tasks=[
    
      ];
      void addTask(String newTaskTitle){
        final task2= task(name: newTaskTitle);
        tasks.add(task2);
        notifyListeners();
      }
      void udatetask(task task){
        task.toggleDone();
        notifyListeners();
      }
      void deleteTask(task task){
        tasks.remove(task);
        notifyListeners();
      }
    
    }
```

//task modal

```
    class task{
      final String name;
      bool isDone;
      task( {this.isDone=false,required this.name});
      void toggleDone(){
        isDone=!isDone;
      }
    }
```

//another page

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class ListTiling extends StatelessWidget {


      final bool isChecked;
      final String taskText;
      final Function(bool?) chCallback;
      final VoidCallback longPress;
      ListTiling({required this.isChecked,required this.taskText,required this.chCallback,required this.longPress});


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListTile(
          onLongPress:longPress,

            title: Text(taskText,style: TextStyle(
              decoration: isChecked?TextDecoration.lineThrough:null
            ),),
            trailing:Checkbox(activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                value: isChecked,onChanged:chCallback ) );
      }
    }
```

I made a todo app with the help of provider package, but whenever restart my app it can't save the last added items. please take a look at my code.
This is my code, I have separated the pages with named comments so that you can have no problem in understanding.
As you can see it is working properly but whenever I restart my app, all the added items will no longer be available and open from a cold start.

Comment: When you create the TaskData class, you initialize the todos like this: `List<task> tasks=[];` meaning that when the app starts, the tasks will be empty. If you want to store the tasks so that you don't lose them, please use the following package [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Comment: You can also store your saved tasks using Firebase Cloud Firestore like in this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EV2DyrKOqrY&t=563s)

Comment: Can u please explain me how to use shared preference with list. I am new to flutter

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the data at your phone/computer and everytime you restart the app you need to fetch the data back to the list you are using . I will give you 3 ways I know and i have tested

Easy but not for important information: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Medium difficulty reliable , doesnt work with windows (or works with some tricks) :
https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Hard to learn but fast , reliable , works with every platform :
https://pub.dev/packages/hive

Comment: can you please help me in using shared prefernce in my code

Comment: You can start by checking some videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5mYLON1hBM&ab_channel=BenjaminCarlson
afterwards you can port the code and the part you cant get your head around